# How to set up keyboard observer which will work out of my app?

Tags: swift, observers, ios-keyboard-extension

The goal of the app is no matter in which app, but catch each **word** user type on default keyboard. **No** numbers - I don't want to get financial info accidentally.

Is this even possible? 
If so, what should I use? ...or maybe you have snipped to share?
If no, what is the best way to count the most common words for a particular user from default keyboard?

Comment: Thankfully this is not possible.

Comment: Lol, this is not possible, I think you should discuss with Apple and tell them that you want to access the work from Keyboard which user has entered in his iPhone.